# Get available space of a connected USB Drive through USB OTG

Tags: android, android-file, android-storage, android-usb

With `StorageManager` we can access removable flash drives connected via USB OTG to Android smartphones:

```
val storageManager = context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
storageManager.storageVolumes
    .forEach { volume ->
        Timber.d("uuid: ${volume.uuid}, storageUuid: ${volume.storageUuid}, path: ${volume.directory}, desc: ${volume.getDescription(context)}, state: ${volume.state}, isDir: ${volume.directory?.isDirectory}, isRemovable: ${volume.isRemovable}\nallocatedBytes: ${volume.storageUuid?.let { storageManager.getAllocatableBytes(it) }}")
    }
```

E.g.:

#1 built-in/internal primary storage:

```
uuid: null
storageUuid: 41217664-9172-527a-b3d5-edabb50a7d69
path: /storage/emulated/0
desc: Internal storage
state: mounted
isDir: true
isRemovable: false
allocatedBytes: 33695051776
```

**#2 usb flash drive:**

```
uuid: 8013-83C4
storageUuid: null
path: /mnt/media_rw/8013-83C4
desc: ESD-USB
state: mounted
isDir: false
isRemovable: true
allocatedBytes: null // because storageUuid is null here
```

We can't get free space from `volumeEsdUsb.directory`:

#1 with `StatFs` there will be an exception:

```
val stats = StatFs(volumeEsdUsb.directory.absolutePath)
val freeSpace = stats.availableBlocksLong * stats.blockSizeLong
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path:
> /mnt/media_rw/8013-83C4   at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:53)
> at android.os.StatFs.(StatFs.java:43)

#2 with `volumeEsdUsb.directory.usableSpace` it just returns `0`

Is there any other solution to get free space on the flash drive Or Android doesn't have anything like this for USB flash drives from the box?

With `Storage Access Framework` there is no info at all about any volume storage, we can just get `treeUri` and use it with `Document` to work with files (create, edit, delete, move, copy)